# How to generate sequence with exclusions in R

Tags: r

I need 4 functions that generate some numbers (each)

1. First function generates sequence from `n` odd numbers except 5, 15, 25, etc...

   example with `n=2`: 1, 1, 3, 3, 7, 7, 9, 9, 11, 11, 13, 13, 17, 17,...
2. Second function generates sequence from `n` even numbers except 10, 20, 30, etc...

   example witn `n=2`: 2, 2, 4, 4, 6, 6, 8, 8, 12, 12, 14, 14, 16, 16,...
3. Third function generates sequence from `n` numbers from 5 by 10

   example witn `n=2`: 5, 5, 15, 15, 25, 25,...
4. Fourth function generates sequence from `n` numbers from 10 by 10

   example witn `n=2`: 10, 10, 20, 20, 30, 30,...

Each function has to get vector `1: N` and `n` as inputs.

For example,

```
f1(1:10, 3)
> 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 7, 7, 7, 9

f2(1:5, 10)
> 2, 2, 2, 2, 2

f3(1:15, 5)
> 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25

f4(1:2, 1)
> 10, 20
```

I have some decision for first two functions but I don`t know how to exclude some numbers:

```
f1 <- function(x) 2*((x-1) %/% 10) + 1 # goes 1, 3, 5, etc for n = 10
f2 <- function(x) 2*((x-1) %/% 10 + 1) # goes 2, 4, 6, etc for n = 10
```

Comment: Ask one question at a time. Also, while your functions apparently demand two inputs, you have written f1 and f2 as functions of one variable...

Answer (score 0):

why not use `seq` and `rep` ?

```
n = 25
nrep = 2 # number of repetitions

by5 <- sort(rep(seq(5, n, by = 10), nrep )) # numbers from 5 by 10
by5 

by10 <- sort(rep(seq(10, n, by = 10), nrep )) # numbers from 10 by 10 
by10

odd <- sort(rep(seq(1, n, by = 2), nrep )) # odd number
odd[!odd %in% by5] # remove all the by5 values

even <- sort(rep(seq(2, n, by = 2), nrep )) # Even numbers
even[!even %in% by10] # remove all the by 10 values
```

output

---

```
> [1]  5  5 15 15 25 25
> [1] 10 10 20 20
> [1]  1  1  3  3  7  7  9  9 11 11 13 13 17 17 19 19 21 21 23 23
> [1]  2  2  4  4  6  6  8  8 12 12 14 14 16 16 18 18 22 22 24 24.
```